# ADFS 3 Customise Login Message to Indicate Account Lockout

Tags: adfs3.0

Using AD FS 3.0, when a user enters their username or password incorrectly they get a message

`'Incorrect user ID or password. Type the correct user ID and password, and try again.'`

If the user locks their account with too many failed attempts, they continue to get the exact same message, which is misleading.

Is it possible to inform the user that their account has been locked?